# SQL statement by time and name

Tags: php, sql

I am struggling how to solve a problem with sql and (php).

I have a production line, in which every product get scanned when it got through
a maschine tool station in the line. As there are a bunch of maschine tools in the line,
every product is scanned multiple times through its way.

This scan is getting obviously very big and a easy example of it would be look like:

```
maschinetoolnumber          Date/Time             Workpiece
20                          8:50                  46
30                          8:51                  56
40                          8:52                  34
30                          8:53                  46
70                          8:53                  77
```

I sorted it by time now and the whole production line is working at every
place the hole time. As you see number 46 gets uploaded in maschine tool number
30 three minutes after 20, because it needs to pass 20 before it comes to 30.

What I basically want to know is how many workpieces are between all of these
maschine tools.

Is there any way in SQL to just get the last scan of every workpiece, so that
I can easily sort them by maschine tool numbers and see how many crossed which maschine tool
last?

Additionally I also want to sort out everything which crossed the last Maschine tool Station,
because its not in the line anymore.

So the Result I want to have here would be like:

```
maschinetoolnumber          Date/Time             Workpiece

30                          8:51                  56
40                          8:52                  34
30                          8:53                  46
70                          8:53                  77
```

Number 46 with Mmschinetoolnumber 20. is away now because it already passed maschinetoolnumber 30.

Comment: What do you mean by the `last Maschine tool Station`

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

What you could start with is

```
SELECT Workpiece, max(maschinetoolnumber) FROM `tablename` group by Workpiece
```

This would return the highest maschinetoolnumber each workpiece has passed through.

Comment: This is a very good idea! I'll try it. If you got more just tell me. thanks

Comment: @clanky1997 That's great! Please upvote the answer if it helped you!

Comment: I think the problem is that this is only returning rows with the highest maschinetoolnumber. In case the workpiece didnt reached it yet it wont be on the table after this. At least this what I think after trying something equal on another database

Comment: @clanky1997 so what output are you expecting?

Comment: Look at this Database. The Problem shall be equal if we want to list the Highest CustomerID of every Country (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_where)

Comment: Because of `GROUP BY` it will return the highest maschinetoolnumber for each workpiece. The output will therefore have one row for all workpieces @clanky1997

Comment: I think you are right. I maybe add something on monday when I can try it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the number of rows since the last time a workpiece was seen.  If so, then:

```
select t.*,
       (seqnum - lag(seqnum) over (partition by workpiece order by datetime) - 1) as num_between
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by datetime) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

Actually, I could interpret this as just how many workpieces are in the data.  If that is the case, then:

```
select count(distinct workpiece)
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at my Problem. No, I would say this is not what I want. Every workpiece produces multiple rows in the Database, due it passes multiple stations and I want to list every workpiece only once with the last Station this workpiece acutally passed.

Comment: That is how I can continue to make a statement how many workpieces are at the moment between of a station and its predecessor or its successor